# SignalR: "The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection" error with windows auth website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an MVC 5 website running signalR 2.1.0 using Windows Authentication.  Because I'm using windows auth login/logout is handled automatically by IIS.  Occassionally I'm getting a 403 error saying "Unrecognized user identity. The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection."  This doesn't happen all the time, and I can't seem to find a pattern to when it does and does not work.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Here is the code on the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            SignalRSetup();
        });

        function SignalRSetup() {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var hub = $.connection.tokenRequestHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            hub.client.updateFromService = function(tokenRequestID, message, success) {
                var msg = "Token Request ID {0} => {1}".format(tokenRequestID, message);
                var notyType = (success) ? 'success' : 'error';
                noty({ text: msg, type: notyType, timeout: 2000 });
                if (success) {
                    refreshGrids();
                }
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();//this is where it errors!
        }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've run into the same issue, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet (in fairness, I haven't devoted more than about an hour to it).  It seems that the issue happens much more often on postbacks.  So I post a model to the controller to (for example) save a user, then I redirect to the user list.  The user list will have this problem.  If I just navigate to the user list then it's fine.  

Let me know if you find anything!

Answer (score 6):

I think I fixed the issue by adding an `[Authorize]` attribute to my Hub class. It's only been a few hours, but my SignalR powered page is behaving much better.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to disable Anonymous Authentication in the IIS settings.

Comment: Thanks for this! Been trying to solve this for hours. Just a couple of lines of code required, nice!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found other than disable Anonymous Authentication is to add

```
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
```

to `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method in the `Startup` class.

Comment: [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize] can be used to configure this per hub or method