# How to debug sporadic 403 connection issues with angular-signalr-hub and windows authenitification

Tags: angularjs, signalr, windows-authentication

I am using signalR with signalr-hub and a windows authentication ASP.net Web Api project.

I have created two hubs in my project that both subscribe to the stateChanged and errorHandler listeners. Sometimes, the page loads without issue, but other times a 403 connection issue is thrown. The error message is as follows:

```
Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
```

This is sometimes followed by the error message:

```
Error: Error during start request. Stopping the connection.
responseText: "Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection."
```

I believe that the error is caused by a race condition with windows authentication. That when the browser is first loaded the connection is anonymous by default, then signalR starts to connect, then windows auth returns the actual user, then SignalR notes that the connection has changed mid request and throws an error.

I have so far looked in trying to delay the connection to signalR with a $timeout to wait for Windows Auth first, but this only seemed to create more frequent errors.

I will look to supply more information with this question soon, in the meantime, I would appreciate any general ideas in how to solve\ get around\ debug this issue.

Comment: Try moving authentication to app.run. Then you could do a number of things on successful authentication like broadcast the user was authenticated, set the loggedInUser variable on your auth service, etc.

Comment: Using windows authentication, it just happens without any js code. I'm not sure if I understand on how to move authentication to this section.

Comment: Do you ever send the server a user name and password? How does the server know which user it needs to authenticate?

Comment: Generally no. only when logging onto my desktop. Windows Authentification picks up the user from active directory and uses that. The exception being when I am running automated tests with web-driver and a popup box opens on page load asking for windows authentication details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to disable anonymous authentication. Otherwise if SignalR is connecting and authentication transitions from anonymous to user authentication whilst the signalr request is processing, then an error is thrown.

Anonymous authentication can be disabled in web.config as follows:

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    ...
```

I found this answer here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25554390/2945345)